# Access 2016 VBA - Cannot update. Database or object is read-only error

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to import data from an Excel file into an Access database.  When I try to execute the sql statement, I get the database or object is read-only message.

Following is the sql statement and vStr value

```
vSQL = "INSERT INTO [tbl_Stage] ([BATID], [AGNCY_NAM], [CNTRCTNBR], [CTTNNBR], [ISSDTE], [ISSUETIME], [VIOLT_CDE], [VIOLT_TYPE], [CTTNAMT], [ADMFEE], [RENTGP]) " & _
"SELECT [BATID], [AGNCY_NAM], [CNTRCTNBR], [CTTNNBR], [ISSDTE], [ISSUETIME], [VIOLT_CDE], [VIOLT_TYPE], [CTTNAMT], [ADMFEE], [RENTGP] " & _
"FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;Database=" & vStr

db.Execute vSQL, dbFailOnError
```

Example of string vStr is set to:
`[C:\APS\Projects\In Work\Citations Management Database\Sample 3.csv].[MonCollRpt 09072$]`

I'm not sure why I'm getting this message.  The file I'm pulling data from is a CSV file.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance....

Comment: Did you check to see if the file is read only?

Comment: Did you really set the value of `vStr` after you tried to use it? Or is the code in your question just not in the right order? Also, you need quotes around strings.

Comment: Also access has a wizard for importing data under the Ribbon's External Data Tab.

Comment: @braX..........(1) Yes.....I did check and the file is not read-only, (2) vStr is set before the execute.  I just included it there so everyone could see the value, and (3) I do have quotes around the string.....

Comment: @mazoula.........I'm aware of the wizard and tried using it but was having trouble with a couple of fields due to data issues.......

Comment: @braX...........The FROM statement references Excel 12.0 should it reference CSV instead?.....

Comment: After doing some research, I changed the FROM clause to:
FROM [text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited(,);Database=" & vStr,  Now I'm getting a syntax error in the from clause error message

Comment: What is `.[MonCollRpt 09072$]`?

Comment: @June7..........that was the sheet name when I opened the csv file in Excel.  I solved my issue by putting brackets around the csv file name